# How to create an array and put into listbox

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have this code which seems to work just fine. The only problem is that if I am in the textbox and then double click the button or double click the enter key I get an exception here

"If GotxtBox.Text < 10 Then"

it says "invalid case exception was unhandeled"
"conversion from string to type double is not valid" How do I stop this from happening?

```
Private Sub GoBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GoBtn.Click

    If GotxtBox.Text < 10 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Number can not be less than 10")
        GotxtBox.Clear()
        Return
    End If
    If GotxtBox.Text > 100 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Number can not be greater than 100")
        GotxtBox.Clear()
        Return
    End If

    Dim number As Integer = Val(GotxtBox.Text) ' get number
    ' add the number to the end of the numberListBox
    GoLstBox.Items.Add(number)

    If GoLstBox.Items.Count = 20 Then
        GoBtn.Enabled = False
        MessageBox.Show("Exactly Twenty Numbers Must Be Entered")

    End If
    GotxtBox.Clear()
    GotxtBox.Focus()


End Sub
```

Comment: Your title doesn't seem to match the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Textboxes contain Text, and "10" is not the same as the value 10.  You need to convert the text before you compare.  Look at `Integer.Tryparse` and/or `Convert.ToInt32`.

You do something like that later with `Val`, but that too should be changed to `TryParse`.  The NET Val is not the same as the VB6 Val.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim text As String = GotxtBox.Text 
Dim value As Double

If Double.TryParse(text, value) Then
    If value < 10 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Number can not be less than 10")
        GotxtBox.Clear()
        Return
    End If

    If value > 100 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Number can not be greater than 100")
        GotxtBox.Clear()
        Return
    End If
Else
   'error, cannot convert
    GotxtBox.Clear()
    Return
End If
```

Comment: should I change this then or leave alone  Dim number As Integer = Val(GotxtBox.Text) ' get number
    ' add the number to the end of the numberListBox
    GoLstBox.Items.Add(number

Comment: you can if you dont plan on handling any errors during parsing.. you could just have IF instead.

Comment: would that be like a try catch Exception

Comment: sort of.. basically, what Double.TryParse does is try to convert the string to a double value. if it cant, it will return FALSE. You can either do something inside the ELSE block, or just leave it out entirely and just use an IF. It depends on your situation.

Comment: I tried the code but now it put a 0 in the listbox when you click the button twice or even once for that matter. shouldn't the <10 stop that. If I enter 1 the message box diaplays

Comment: I wonder if 0 isn't getting parsed correctly.. Add "Return" inside the ELSE statement

Comment: return didn't do anything, one way or another